# Controller test: RuntimeError: @controller is nil. How to refer to controller if the controller is in a subfolder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, testing

I have the following controllers:

- /controllers/api/base_controller.rb
- /controllers/api/v1/articles_controller.rb

When running my controller tests for the articles, I get the error `RuntimeError: @controller is nil: make sure you set it in your test's setup method`. My test file starts with:

```
require 'test_helper'
class ApiArticlesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  etc...
```

What should be on the `class` line though? I've tried several versions but without success.

Comment: What is the name of the class in `/controllers/api/v1/articles_controller.rb`?

Comment: The first lines of that controller are: `module Api` ; `module V1` ; `class ArticlesController < Api::BaseController`

Comment: So you should refer to your controller as `Api::V1::ArticlesController`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller name is scoped so you should refer to it as `Api::V1::ArticlesController`

Scoped means it's name is in the scope ("under") another module, in your case there's two of them `Api` and `V1`.

Changing your test to `class Api::V1::ArticlesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase` should fix your problem.

EDIT

If above doesn't work you can also do following

```
class ApiArticlesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  tests Api::V1::ArticlesController
```